# In ASP.Net, how to get the file path in another project?

Tags: asp.net

Currently I have a web project **A**, it has one button, and the button on-click event will call a function in another project **B**.

Now within this function, I have to access a file which is under project **B**, with path like **/B/Template/myFile.doc**

I have tried to use method like `Server.MapPath()` and `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` in this function, but both method is getting relative path to project **A** rather than **B**

I guess indeed it is the correct behavior but how can I get the path of this file in project **B** successfully? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Write a web service/WebAPI function which returns `realpath` of application `A`.

Comment: @AVD Thanks for the reply, I think you meant `realpath` of `B`? Just one more question...is that the only way to achieve this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you want to call a function from the file? or need file path? If you want to call a function, cant you add project reference and then call using the reference? whats the purpose of file path?

Comment: @TheUknown I have to open the file to do something, the file is like a template of a report to be generated

Comment: Well, you can also return the file path via the function. Add project reference and write a function in that project which return the template/path

Comment: @shole Yes. I guess. It is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be:

1. Import project B into project A.
2. Write a function in project B that returns the full path to the file.
3. Call that function in project A.

Hope that helps!